# 3d array as function argument

Tags: c, arguments, multidimensional-array

I have a function which takes a 2d-array as an argument. Then I have a 3d-array e.g. `temp[5][100][100]`. I want to pass the 2d portion of this array to the function. How can I do this?

```
int inteference_sets(int array[][],int array_size,int max_channel){
     //function codes
}
int main(){
    int k;

    int temp[5][100][100];
    for(k=1;k<=4;k++){
       interference_sets(temp[k], , ) //this is how the program intends to work
    }
 }
```

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: By "second portion" I assume you mean any of the five 100x100 partitions, by reference/address.

Comment: yeah.. i think you got me right !

Comment: Then you chose... wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define DIM1 100
#define DIM2 100

int inteference_sets(int (*array)[DIM2], int array_size, int max_channel)
{
     int row, col;

     for( row = 0; row < array_size; row++ )
     {
         for( col = 0; col < DIM2; col++ )
         {
             int value = array[row][col];
             //function codes
         }
     }
} 

int main()
{
    int k;

    int temp[5][DIM1][DIM2];

    for(k=1;k<=4;k++)
    {
       interference_sets(temp[k], DIM1, ) //this is how the program intends to work
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1. Also note that unlike C++, almost all reasonable intelligent C implementations support VLAs (variable length arrays) including VLA parameters. This allows you to specify at runtime what the compiler would normally require constants to deduce. [See it live for an example](http://ideone.com/WOTbQr). Nice answer.